# How can i change SQL date format to: 12th Jun 2021. (as example)

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I'm trying to insert data from .csv file, but because of the date format I'm using - import causes it to set to 00-00-0000

import settings:
format - CSV using load data (otherwise it causing errors and failing to import)
Specific format options: none

Errors I'm receiving after import:

- Data truncated for column...
  my_date sets to 0000-00-00, even with 'DD/MMM/yyyy' date format,

my csv file structure: (just in case if i need to use specific format)

name;1;1st Jan 2021;2st Jan 2021;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Technically, I could format it manually to 12 jun 2021 / 12.06.2021 / 12/06/2021 but I would like to avoid that.

Sorry if it's a dumb question and the answer is simple, but I have no idea how to fix it. :)

I already tried this but still nothing.

```
SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';
select date_format(my_date, 'DD MMM yyyy') FROM table1;
select date_format(my_date, 'DD/MMM/yyyy') FROM table1;
```

Comment: Provide code-formatted CREATE TABLE of the table where your data must be imported into, and CSV file example (3-5 rows, code-formatted).

Comment: How **exactly** do you import the data? Also, can you share sample input data (more than one line)? Finally, share how this is a programming-related problem

Comment: You can't insert data with `SELECT`, let alone from a CSV. What are you doing exactly? `date_format()` expects a valid date in the first place.

Comment: *name;1;1st Jan 2021; **2st** Jan 2021;;;;;;;;;;;;;* - ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should import your date columns as text data type, and make transformations later! Please follow this steps:

Import Wizard

[image: Import Wizard]

Then Update your columns:

```
UPDATE myimport
SET StartDate = STR_TO_DATE(StartDate,'%D %b %Y');
UPDATE myimport
SET FinishDate = STR_TO_DATE(FinishDate,'%D %b %Y');
```

Then Change data type to DATE(or preferably date time):

```
ALTER TABLE myimport
MODIFY COLUMN StartDate DATE, 
MODIFY COLUMN FinishDate DATE;
```

If we check the data,

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myimport;
+------+------+------------+------------+
| name | Row  | StartDate  | FinishDate |
+------+------+------------+------------+
| name |    1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 |
+------+------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If we check the datatype to ensure that It is date:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE myimport;
+----------+------------------------------------------------------
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------
| myimport | CREATE TABLE `myimport` (
  `name` text,
  `Row` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinishDate` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what i was looking for, i was thinking about importing it as text, but i though that will make it more complicated.

Comment: You're welcome! Then your reasoning is correct! A solution is better than no-solution at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can transform and use the below query to transform the date.

```
select date_format(`created_at`, '%D %b %Y') FROM product_attributes;
```

[Please see this pic for the query result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG0aL.png)

[You can use this SQL query to see the DB table query and insert query and use this for reference.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/pu9uuygtd09867k/product_attributes.sql/file)

Comment: Please share more details. How could a `SELECT` query help to insert data from a CSV file?

Comment: are you using import records directly to your DB using my SQL server import option?
 Please give me the query and table details. I will try it from my end and let you know.

Comment: Select used for format date. Please tell me what you want to do.
Please give me more information.